# 2 button click function overlap each other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm still learning Jquery and currently facing a problem when making multiple button.
I got 2 button that will show a div box in the middle of the page and also put overlay background color and etc.
The main Jquery code I made are currently like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mail_box').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.modal_1').toggleClass("reveal");
        $("section").toggleClass("body_black");
        $('.color_back').toggleClass("overlay");
        $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
      });
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tell_box').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.modal_2').toggleClass("reveal");
        $("section").toggleClass("body_black");
        $('.color_back').toggleClass("overlay");
        $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
      });
  });
```

The main button are .mail_box and .tell_box. When clicked it will reveal div called .modal_1 or .modal_2 respectively. I tried using .stopPropagation(); but it doesn't work as I thought it would be.
My Questions is :
・How can I prevent .modal_1 and .modal_2 from overlaping when clicking .mail_box or .tell_box ?
・Is there any way to remove all the toggled class when clicking outside .modal_1 and .modal_2 div ?

Thank You in advance

Edit :

Sorry I forgot to include the HTML and CSS so here it is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mail_box').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.modal_1').toggleClass("reveal");
    $("section").toggleClass("body_black");
    $('.color_back').toggleClass("overlay");
    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tell_box').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.modal_2').toggleClass("reveal");
    $("section").toggleClass("body_black");
    $('.color_back').toggleClass("overlay");
    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
  });
});
```

```css
.reveal {
  display: flex !important;
}

.body_black {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.no_scroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header .modal_1 {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 30%;
  right: 25%;
  max-width: 920px;
  border: 1.5rem solid #9C004E;
  padding: 1rem;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_title {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #306CB4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_mail_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_mail_box img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_mail_box .email {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #0F4087;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_time {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_time .time_title {
  background-color: #0F4087;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_time .time_hour {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0F4087;
}

header .modal_1 .modal_note {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0 2rem;
}

header .modal_2 {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 30%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 920px;
  border: 1.5rem solid #9C004E;
  padding: 1rem;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_title {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #306CB4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_mail_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_mail_box img {
  width: 4.5rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_mail_box .email {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #0F4087;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_time {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_time .time_title {
  background-color: #0F4087;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_time .time_hour {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0F4087;
}

header .modal_2 .modal_note {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0 2rem;
}

header .main_menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper {
  height: 6.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .desc_box {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .desc_box p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #9C004E;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper .tell_box {
  width: 7rem;
  background-color: #E61F78;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper .tell_box img {
  width: 2.5rem;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper .tell_box p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper .mail_box {
  width: 7rem;
  background-color: #9C004E;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper .mail_box img {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

header .main_menu .main_menu_wrapper .menu_box_wrapper .mail_box p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.outer_part .part_1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(img/back_img_1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .logo_icon {
  padding: 1rem 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .logo_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_left {
  width: calc((100% / 2) - 1rem);
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_left .title_1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_left .title_2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_left .title_3 {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #FFC200;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #0F4087;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_right {
  width: calc((100% / 2) - 1rem);
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_right .title_img {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_title_wrap .title_wrap_right .title_img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.outer_part .part_1 .color_back .main_button_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="modal_1">
    <p class="modal_title">
      Life Card<br>Information Center
    </p>
    <div class="modal_mail_box">
      <img src="img/modal_mail.png" alt="Email">
      <span class="email">email.co.jp</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_time">
      <p class="time_title">
        Horário de Atendimento
      </p>
      <p class="time_hour">
        24 horas, 365 dias
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="modal_note">
      ※Caution
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal_2">
    <p class="modal_title">
      Information Center
    </p>
    <div class="modal_mail_box">
      <img src="img/tell_blue.png" alt="Telephone Icon">
      <span class="email">Phone Number</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_time">
      <p class="time_title">
        Horário de Atendimento
      </p>
      <p class="time_hour">
        9：30～17：30
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="modal_note">
      （segunda à sexta-feira, exceto feriados）
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="main_menu max_width">
    <div class="main_menu_wrapper max_width">
      <div class="desc_box">
        <p>
          Clique ao lado para consultas e solicitações de formulários
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_box_wrapper">
        <div class="tell_box">
          <img src="img/tell.png" alt="">
          <p>
            Tell
          </p>
        </div>
        <a class="mail_box">
          <img src="img/mail.png" alt="">
          <p>
            Mail
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="outer_part">
  <section class="part_1">
    <div class="color_back">
      <div class="logo_title max_width">
        Logo Title
      </div>
      <div class="main_title_wrap max_width">
        <div class="title_wrap_left">
          <p class="title_1 font">
            Paragraph 1
          </p>
          <p class="title_2">
            Paragraph 2
          </p>
          <div class="title_3">
            Paragraph 3
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title_wrap_right">
          <div class="title_img">
            <img src="img/card_img.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Update :
@freedomn-m Thanks for your suggestion.
Because I don't really understand what you're suggestions, I ended up making my own solution.
I made a close button [X] and making rules where if one button are clicked the other button are temporarily disabled, and can be re-enabled again after clicking the close button.
My Jquery solution are as bellow.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tell_box').click(function () {
    $('.menu_button').prop("disabled", true);
    $('.modal_2').addClass("reveal");
    $("section").toggleClass("body_black");
    $('.color_back').toggleClass("overlay");
    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
  });
  $('.mail_box').click(function () {
    $('.menu_button').prop("disabled", true);
    $('.modal_1').addClass("reveal");
    $("section").toggleClass("body_black");
    $('.color_back').toggleClass("overlay");
    $("body").toggleClass("no_scroll");
  });
  $(".close_button").click(function () {
    $('.menu_button').prop("disabled", false);
    $('.modal_2').removeClass("reveal");
    $('.modal_1').removeClass("reveal");
    $("section").removeClass("body_black");
    $('.color_back').removeClass("overlay");
    $("body").removeClass("no_scroll");
  });
});
```

Comment: You should include your HTML as well.

Comment: @Hp93 Sorry I forgot to include the HTML. I edited my previous post and include the HTML also the CSS.

Comment: 1) separate show and hide functions, don't use `toggle` - with toggle clicking tell =show but then clicking mail doesn't =show it shows the mail dialog but hides the backdrop etc.   2) add a click handler to `document` or the backdrop to hide the dialog